# Error in matlab textread command when trying to retrieve a txt file

Tags: matlab, import, textscan

I am trying to retrieve a txt file from matlab with the textread command but i get the below error every time. I have tried using the textscan command as well but Matlab responds that there is too many output arguments.

Error in textread (line 171)
[varargout{1:nlhs}]=dataread('file',varargin{:}); %#ok

```
[mydates, x_open, x_high, x_low, x_close, x_adjclose, my_volume] = textread('C:\Users\yousu\Documents\MATLAB\TSLA_prices_Jun2020_Feb2022.txt', '%f %f %f %f %f%f', 'headerlines', 1);
```

i have also tried removing the full pathway and using only the file name but with no success

Comment: Did you try using textscan ?

Comment: yes i have, it says too many output arguments when i do that

Comment: Try removing the ouput arguments just to see the ans

Comment: I looks like you are requesting 7 outputs but I only see 6 `%f` in your call to textread.  Can you provide a sample of the text file you are trying to read?